# CLLocationManager updating every second

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I'm using a CLLocationManager to get a users location (primarily running in the background). I create it like so and set the accuracy to best lowest as to have minimal impact on battery.

```
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
```

I then implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

I'm running the application in the simulator and simulate a 'freeway drive'. The location manager delegate method seems to be updating every second which I'm thinking isn't correct as the 'car' is probably not travelling at 3km/sec (in fact it's travelling at 50km/hr).

Is my understanding of this functionality correct or am I missing something? Will this have a large negative impact on battery life? Would this change in real life usage depending on cell tower/GPS/wifi signals?

Comment: Use `distanceFilter` if you want this called less frequently. Use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` instead of `startUpdatingLocation` and disable background operation if you really want to conserve battery.

Comment: BTW, if supporting iOS 6 and later only, use `didUpdateLocations` nowadays.